# Android google-services.json file

Tags: android

I Added firebase integration to my app and added google-services.json file do finish integration and connect my app with firebase. But now after that I deleted google-services.json file and my app works and builds totally fine.
What is the next time my app will use this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `google-services.json` is cached and that's why it's still working fine. If you
**Invalidate cache** & **Restart Android Studio**, then it will stop working.

It's obligatory to keep the file if you want to keep on using the Firebase integration

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete this file because your project will need it.
It contains all firebase project id's and settings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, My Android Studio wasn't updating the **google-services.json** file even after **File** >> **Invalidate Cache & Restart**. I had to delete everything from the "**build**" directory and it then took the new google-services.json file.